# block a group chat in skype

Tags: chat, block, skype

Is there any way to block a group chat in skype without blocking all of them. I don't want to leave the group, since which causes to re-add me by my friends. Want to escape from the group without notifying the other group members. Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: This belongs to the Skype forum.

Comment: Please tell me, who added the skype tag in here? It has about the 29 followers..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using the Notifications Settings from the Conversations menu. This makes it possible to stay in chats but without getting all annoying notifications all the time. Just enter you name/nickname and Skype will only notify you when your name is mentioned.

Comment: This post is useful but I believe there is growing need of feature ie, blocking chat group which skype has to implement